# how to identify a transaction?

Tags: transactions, database

I'm trying to store transactions in a database and want to generate a unique identifier from the transaction data.  It must not change   My data source is api.etherscan.io, and I am currently making an id from the transaction blockHash + hash, eg:

Given this transaction (with hashes are shortened for clarity):

```
{ blockNumber: '6564583',
     timeStamp: '1540241421',
     hash:
      '0xf59dc77',
     nonce: '34',
     blockHash:
      '0x19f51a3',
     transactionIndex: '141',
     from: '0x83b2d2289f1a666659a0261f4e0cd046386d586f',
     to: '0x164013dfdfbf67b0dfca341ff12c4a616fb2a44a',
```

My database id would be something like `0xf59dc77_0x19f51a3`.

Is this enough to guarantee uniqueness, or is there more?

Comment: The transaction hash itself (not shortened) is enough to guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: So there's only ever 1 transaction per hash?

Comment: Yes. Per the answer below, it's pretty much impossible for these hashes to collide.

Answer (score 3):

Transaction hashes are unique until there is a hash collision.

A hash collision occurs if two different inputs produce the same hash output. The transaction hash is *64 hexadecimal characters (2 charactes per byte) = 32 bytes = 32 * 8 bits = 256 bits*. Ethereum blockchain has some 500 million transactions currently. Each of those has a possibility to cause a transaction hash collision.

We can calculate the probability of a transaction hash collision with a calculator: http://davidjohnstone.net/pages/hash-collision-probability . If you enter the aforementioned numbers you get a probability of 1.186945×10<sup>-48</sup> which is rather..small.

So, for all practical purposes, you will not get a hash collision.

However if you only store a *part* of the hash the odds of getting a collision increase exponentially. If you are using 16 characters that means 128 bits. Given the same calculator the chance is 3.673419×10<sup>-22</sup>. That's a lot more than the previous one but still very very small, so you should be ok. So the (partial) hashes will most likely stay unique.

Comment: A tx hash has 64 hexadecimal digits so 4 bits per digit, 64 * 4 = 256 bits per hash.

Comment: It depends on the characters but "normal" characters take 1-2 bytes in UTF-8. And at least according to https://onlineutf8tools.com/convert-utf8-to-binary one tx hash takes 512 bits / 64 bytes.

Comment: Transaction hashes on Ethereum are the output of keccak256 which is 256 bits. I never mentioned characters because of the ambiguity but digits instead.

Comment: Transaction hashes are indeed 32 bytes (256 bits).

Comment: I was sure I had some conversion mistake there. Mistook "64 hex chars" to be the same as "64 chars". Fixed now. Thanks all for the comments.

Comment: sorry, I wasn't suggesting shortening anything, that was just to make my question a bit more readable.  I guess what I want to know is, does a hash represent ETH flowing from one exactly one wallet to exactly one other wallet?  If so, the hash will be a suitable id in my database for the transaction.  In the bitcoin world this doesn't appear to be the case. For example: https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/1781d6e55fdf0e0fd22800ddd46cb1f24c2b27d33385c3b92685565e879753a5

Comment: Yes, the hash is a suitable id for the transaction as it "contains" all the details